# change column data type to date when only year available pandas

Tags: pandas

The colum data which is year has only year( int64) ex 1961 and not as 1961-01-01
when I try to chage to date formate as

```
dfda['Founded']= pd.to_datetime(dfda['Founded'])
```

the output is **1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001961** which is wrong , is there any simple way or should we reformate the column to 1961-01-01

Comment: Use `dfda['Founded']= pd.to_datetime(dfda['Founded'], format='%Y')`

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
  str(dfda['Founded'])
```